# SQL - Add a border bottom when column value changes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, toad

I'm trying to add a border bottom red style to a table when the column value changes.

[image]

As shown in the picture, I want to add a bottom border when `FamilyID` changes it's value.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out a CASE WHEN THEN ELSE statement but there's no way for me to compare previous and next values. I'm still pretty new to SQL so there's ALOT to learn.

Comment: you have to do this using jquery, css based on value change flag

Comment: Ahhhhhhh.... I see!
I can definitely try that out then; much more comfortable with jquery and css.

Comment: so suppose your FamilyID = 2 & 4 change (you have to set a flag for this), then add the hidden column.  then in jquery based on hidden column value set border-bottom: solid red;

Comment: sweet, i'll try this out today

Comment: @Piyush How exactly would i go about integrating the value change flag? Would i just compare values using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just went about using a SQL workaround using the LAG command.
Used that as a flag to indicate when value has changed and set the CSS command for the event. Thanks @Piyush for the suggestion to use a flag!

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have implemented same thing on classic report of employee ,
 you can check url https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=26095  with
userid: AMOL.PATIL@VYOMLABS.COM
pass  : Unicorn@123

Code in execute JavaScript page load section:

```
 var previous=null;
 var flag;
 $("td[headers=DEPTNO]").each(function() {


 if(previous==null){
      previous=$(this).text();
      flag='true';
  }

 if($(this).text()==null ||$(this).closest('tr').next().find('[headers="DEPTNO"]').text()==null) {

 }
 else
 { 
   if($(this).text()!=$(this).closest('tr').next().find('[headers="DEPTNO"]').text()) {
    previous=$(this).text();
    if(flag=='false')
      flag='true';
    else
    {
    flag='false';

    }
   }

  if(previous==$(this).text()&& flag=='false') {

    flag='true';

    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
    $(this).closest('tr').next().addClass("myclass");
  }
}

 });
```

code for inline css section of page:

```
table.uReportStandard > tbody tr.myclass > td 
{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Output : 
Similarly you can also implement same thing by just changing headers.In your case it may be FAMILYID which will replace DEPTNO here.
Please try this code ...