# APEX - How to get line Seperator in Menu

Tags: menu, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a Navigation Bar menu in an Apex 5 app.  Something like 'Info A', 'Info B', 'Logout'.
For 'Info B', it is a drop down menu, which is in 2 categories.  So for example,

```
Set 1
-----------------
Set 2A
Set 2B
Set 2C
Set 2D
```

How do I draw a horizontal line between the 2 sets, that is (ideally) non-selectable?  These are static menu entries, they will not change.

Comment: Could you not define another entry that contains whatever text you like and has no target?

Comment: Hi, To spearate out these category you would require unique category id then you can apply similar logic that i have been provided  for classic report.Though it is not exact solution but can help you to build logic. Hope this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417837/sql-add-a-border-bottom-when-column-value-changes/28560634#28560634

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone still interested in this, this is how you do it:
Create a new List-Entry with **List Entry Label** = '---' (3 dashes), **Target Type = URL** and **URL Target** = 'separator'

Happy apexing